# Pm2 throwing service unavailable error after deployment

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I have been using pm2 to manage my node apps for a while. In deployment steps, pm2 restart is added after deployment finished. But it throws unhandledrejection event in promise js and service becomes unavailable.

when i manually restart pm2 manually issue vanishes. we are using same deployment steps on qa and production. But this issue of taking manual restart of pm2 is only happening at qa environment.

we have tried restart pm2 script in cron job as well but that also doesn't solved our issue.
I suspect may be due to diff in npm, node versions at prod and qa env, the behaviour is different.